# Stop "Could not edit 'http://ajax.googleapis.com....because it is not in the Web site." error message

Tags: visual-studio-2008

The problem:

Visual Studio is indexing the CSS files so that I can have intellisense on my classes (i assume), but I am referencing a Goolge CDN jQuery CSS file and it can't read that file for some reason.

How can I get stop visual studio from checking my CSS files so that I don't get this error?

This is the actual error that VS pops up :

> Could not edit
>   'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/themes/excite-bike/jquery-ui.css'
>   because it is not in the Web site.

Answer (score -1):

Your files must have consistent line endings. Try to format the document using (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) to correct the line endings.

Comment: It's impossible to do that because the files are not in my control. They are hosted at google. `<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />` is how I reference them.